# Report view toggle button status is wrong

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

I set visibility of child group to "Show" when the report is initially run, unfortunately, the toggle button status is "+" when the report presents, but the items in the child group are shown, and then I click on "+", these items are hidden, and status changes to "-",  the status is totally wrong. Is this a bug with report view?

How can I control the status of the toggle button?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but today the same thing happened to me. What you have to do is go to the properties of the TextBox that controls the ToggleButton, and in the InitialToggleState property set it to "true"